# Hibernate didn't create one of tables

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm learning spring..., I build a simple application. 
I have a problem because hibernate does not want to generate one of the models.. 
I do not know what's wrong

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name="access_card")
public class AccessCard implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4015209774835055079L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="key")
    private String key;
    @Column(name="enabled")
    private Boolean enabled;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Other classes are written similarly and everything works.
Error:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
>   executing DDL "create table access_card (id bigint not null, enabled
>   bit, key varchar(255), user_id bigint not null, primary key (id))
>   engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

And properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Generates all tables except this one

Comment: I changed the name of the "key" column and it works

Answer (score 0):

Follow your comment, The problem pointed out at here

```
key varchar(255)
```

The table name is reserved keyword.

See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4453

If you still want it, the solution is https://vladmihalcea.com/escape-sql-reserved-keywords-jpa-hibernate/